# Referencing an uninitialized object during object initialization in Python

Tags: python, object, oop

Essentially, I have a number of objects that I would like to refer to each other.

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self, name="The Room",adj={}):
        self.adj = adj
        self.name = name

room1 = Room({'n':room2,'s':room3})
room2 = Room({'s':room1})
room3 = Room({'n':room1})
```

Since room2 and room3 aren't initialized when room1 is declared, clearly this doesn't work.

I can initialize first and change the adj data later like so:

```
room1 = Room("Room 1")
room2 = Room("Room 2")
room3 = Room("Room 3")

room1.adj = {'n':room2,'s':room3}
room2.adj = {'s':room1}
room3.adj = {'n':room1}
```

But I would prefer a cleaner solution. I'm quite new to Python so I'm not sure what other route I might go.

Comment: As an aside, be careful with using a mutable value as a default argument, it will be created *once* when the function is defined.

Comment: Are you sure you need separate variables for all the rooms? You probably only need the starting room, the rest would be accessed by navigating from there, not using explicit variables.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for that, I might update my IDE to PyCharm to help fill my knowledge gap when it comes to things like this

Comment: @Barmar Yes I believe so, they contain descriptions and object data that I've excluded for simplicity

Comment: @Natty that doesn't really address why you need to use a variable for each room

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean—if not separate variables, what else would I do? The code essentially sets the current room, allows the user to move by inputting the direction, then updates the current room to the value pair of the direction key. Is this a bad method?

Comment: @Natty none of that requires having a separate variable for each room, only a single variable for the current room

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems best, but if you really want something terse you can use the walrus operator.

```
room1 = Room('Room 1', 
    {'n': room2 := Room('Room 2'), 
     's': room3 := Room('Room 3')
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll stick with my code, but it's useful to learn a new operator

Comment: But this does not provide the adjacency dictionary to `room2` and `room1`